# My home directory just goes away. Why?

Tags: filesystem, ext4

I'm running an older Dell GX280, with a new 500GB drive and 2GB RAM. Fresh install with my `~` directory copied from an older HD I got the 500GB to replace. I think I'm running ext4 on both my `/` and `/home` partitions.

And, if I run for a few days, I lose my `~/` directory. By which I mean, I can do anything with any file and directory in `~/` if I know what I'm looking for, but if I do `ls`, or try tab-completion, or try to view it in nautilus, it hangs. Then, I reboot, and everything is back together.

What is it? Where do I start looking for problems? I don't know where to start Googling for the answer.

Here's my `/etc/fstab`

```
jacoby@oz:/var/log$ cat /etc/fstab 
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid -o value -s UUID' to print the universally unique identifier
# for a device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name
# devices that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=4f677505-0b67-47b0-bbb4-858ffc1fe125 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /alt was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=b0eec90c-d312-4123-b78c-7487a3347888 /alt            ext4    defaults        0       2
# /home was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=1def350e-fe9a-40e3-8162-0a9f7ff8d5ef /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=e62cd8c5-6088-44a8-84a6-7d399e42d81d none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0
```

Comment: So, it doesn't go away, it causes a freeze?

Comment: Can you post the contents of your /etc/fstab file?

Comment: Also, what method did you use to do the copying?  And did you copy all the hidden dotfiles from your prior install?

Comment: If there is I/O errors on the partition they should show up in `/var/log/dmesg` use this command to se the logfile `cat /var/log/dmesg` (for the current log) and `cat /var/log/dmesg.0` (for the last boot-log. Please tell if there is any error messages there. Also the output from this command might be helpfull in finding the problem `mount`.

Comment: In addition to what Source Lab mention, one thing that may help is the output of `/usr/bin/strace -s999 /bin/ls ~` when the symptoms appear. If that doesn't hang, `/usr/bin/strace -s999 /bin/ls -l ~`. You'll need to install the `strace` package first. For privacy you may want to replace some file names with `xxx`. Also, does this affect only your home directory, or also other directories (e.g. `/bin/ls ~/bin` if you have a `bin` subdirectory in your home)?

Comment: Can you think of anything “unusual” you've set up that might be filesystem-related, such as NFS, Samba, encryption, SELinux, Apparmor, ...?

Comment: I use FUSE and mount several filesystems. My home box, the main server (three time), a machine or two in the office, a student org's server (twice), and maybe one or two more.

Comment: It doesn't cause a freeze. As long as I don't try to list the files and directories in ~/, I'm free to do whatever I want.

I think I did a cp -r * from the old to the new. I was going from a 40GB drive to a 500GB drive, so I felt comfortable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one thing I can think of that could explain your symptoms. If you have a mount point to a “flaky” filesystem, or a symbolic link to a mount point to a flaky filesystem, in your home directory, then most methods of listing your home directory could hang (including `ls -l`, `ls -F`, `ls --color`, but not plain `/bin/ls`) waiting for that flaky filesystem.

Possible examples of flaky filesystems:

- An NFS/Samba mount where the server is not responding. This is mostly observed in unix enterprise environments.
- A fuse mount that's hung on .

Unmounting the offending filesystem may help; `umount -l` or `umount -f` may be useful in desperate circumstances (read the `mount` man page before using these options). For a fuse filesystem that's waiting on a process that isn't responding, try umounting with `fusermount -u` (or `fusermount -uz` if there are open files), and killing the non-responding process.

Tip: don't mount this kind of filesystems under a directory you traverse often, such as your home directory. Have a dedicated parent directory for such mount points, e.g., `~/mnt`. The same goes for symbolic links that point into these filesystems.

Comment: That's a maybe. I'll have to wait for the next time it happens. I AM using a CRAZY amount of FUSE. I set up my twelve mountpoints in /sshmount and symbolically link to them so that they don't show up when I du in my home directory. I can't say yet that this is definitively it, but it does seem likely. And, thanks.

Comment: Seems like the good way to force the error is to reboot my home machine while still sshfs-mounted. I might try that later today.

Comment: @VarLogRant: Doh, right, I should have thought of this. A crashed fuse daemon would be a modern equivalent of an absent NFS server.

Comment: No biggie. I didn't think to mention it until you mentioned NFS.

Comment: It happened again. I'm sure it's Fuse now.

Comment: When I noticed it happening, I was at home viewing my work machine and could fusermount -u everything but gvfs and one of my sshfs connections. So, it's one or the other.